# QEMU installation is broken

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, virtualization, iso-image, qemu

I am trying to run a Windows 10 VM on Windows 10.

**What I did**

I downloaded QEMU exe, then got Windows Installation Media to get the Windows 10 iso file.
Then I simply moved to the Windows 10.iso file into the QEMU installation folder. Then renamed the Windows 10 iso file to "win10.iso".

Then I ran these commands in the command prompt

`qemu-img.exe create -f qcow2 -o cluster_size=2M win10.qcow2 50G`

`qemu-system-x86_64.exe -boot d -cdrom win10.iso -m 2048 win10.qcow2`

**What happened**

But after running the second one, it gave me this error (the QEMU window popped up though):

```
C:\Users\Zack\Downloads\QEMU>qemu-system-x86_64.exe -boot d -cdrom win10.iso -m 2048 win10.qcow2
qemu-system-x86_64.exe: warning: GdkPixbuf: Cannot open pixbuf loader module file 'C:\Users\Zack\Downloads\QEMU\lib\gdk-pixbuf-2.0\2.10.0\loaders.cache': No such file or directory

This likely means that your installation is broken.
Try running the command
  gdk-pixbuf-query-loaders > C:\Users\Zack\Downloads\QEMU\lib\gdk-pixbuf-2.0\2.10.0\loaders.cache
to make things work again for the time being.
```

How do I fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue with qemu installed via scoop.

To get rid of the warning, just create an empty file `loaders.cache`, i.e.,

```
C:\Users\Zack\Downloads\QEMU\lib\gdk-pixbuf-2.0\2.10.0\loaders.cache
```

in your case.

Comment: The empty file in my case already existed.